# minimum value of a complex inequality

Tags: complex-numbers

If $|z_1 |^2+ |z_2 |^2+ |z_3 |^2+ |z_4 |^2=1$,$z_1+z_2+z_3+z_4=0$,show that minimum value of
$|z_1-z_2 |^2+ |z_2-z_3 |^2+ |z_3-z_4 |^2+ |z_4-z_1 |^2$  is 2.

Answer (score 0):

We must show that the following expression is nonnegative :

$$
q=|z_1-z_2|^2+|z_2-z_3|^2+|z_3-z_4|^2+|z_4-z_1|^2-
2(|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2+|z_3|^2+|z_4|^2)
$$

Now if we put $z_k=x_k+iy_k$ with $x_k,y_k$ real, we have

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
q &=& \sum_{k} (x_k-x_{k+1})^2+(y_k-y_{k+1})^2-2(\sum_{k} x_k^2+y_k^2) \\
&=& -2 (\sum_{k}x_kx_{k+1} +y_ky_{k+1})
\end{array}
$$

But

$$
\sum_{k}x_kx_{k+1}=
x_1x_2+x_2x_3+(x_1+x_3)x_4=
x_1x_2+x_2x_3+(x_1+x_3)(-x_1-x_2-x_3)=-(x_1+x_3)^2
$$

so that

$$
q=2((x_1+x_3)^2+(y_1+y_3)^2)
$$

and we are done.